# How to start off a promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

This may seem like a weird question but allow me to explain:
I have this function that I want to turn into a promise because I believe some events are not firing fully and others are starting before (e.g. the state of playersOverallTotal is wrong because I don't think it has taking into account the code above so I need to *wait* for it to finish before setting state

```
  handleClickTwist() {
    this.dealToPlayer();
    this.forceUpdate();
    let playersDeck = this.state.playersDeck;
    let playersDeckTotal = [];
    for (var i=0; i < playersDeck.length; i++){
      playersDeckTotal.push(playersDeck[i].rankValue)
    }

    let total = playersDeckTotal.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      },
    0);

    this.setState({playersOverallTotal: total});
    this.total();
  };
```

I know promises look something like the below

```
  anotherFunc(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve()
    }
  }
```

and then I can call something like this:

```
this.func().then(() => {
      return this.anotherFunc();
    }).then(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(this.setState({playersOverallTotal: total}))
    }).then(() => {
      return this.anotherFun();
```

but I cant think how to do it for this code so far. or rather, what is the initial function I can call in the `anotherFunc()` to *kick* the function off?

Comment: "what is the initial function I can call in the anotherFunc() to kick the function off?" — That would be `Promise`, which you are already calling there.

Comment: I don't see any async functions in your code. So you should not need a promise. If either `dealToPlayer()` or `forceUpdate()` are async then they should either accept a callback or return a promise. Your problem is not with the `handleClickTwist()` function

Comment: By default, javascript code waits for the previous code to be finished before continuing. Promises and callbacks allow you to do something while some external process is running - for example: loading an image or a json file. In your code I don't see any external process, so your error is most likely just a programming bug. It depends on what your other functions do (dealToPlayer(), forceUpdate(), etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are missing some common understanding:

First, I don't see any possible Problems with your code, that could be solved by promises, but any way, as in your example:

```
anotherFunc(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // do some crazy stuff here
      // if you do an ajax call put "resolve" 
      // into success function after ajax is finished

      if(allIsFine) {
        resolve(passAnyData);
      } else { reject() };
    }
  }
```

then a call

```
anotherFunc().then(function(passAnyData) {
// resolve called with passAnyData


}).catch(function() {
// some error
});
```

Comment: ok sure. let me put it like this:

`let total = playersDeckTotal.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      },
    0);
    console.log(playersDeckTotal, 'deck');
    console.log(total, 't0t1'); //logs 19 as expected 

    this.setState({playersOverallTotal: total});
    console.log(this.state.playersOverallTotal, 'tot');` //logs 14 because it discounts the final number.

why would it do this?

Comment: ok solved, I needed a timeout. will mark yours as correct though